# jQueryMobile script runs twice on each pageload

Tags: jquery-mobile

I've been trying to get a script that inserts a div of text after the first and second paragraph of an article to work in jQueryMobile. It works on the first pageload, but on the second it loads the content twice, and the third time it's loaded three times, and so on.

The jQueryMobile libraries and my script is loaded in the head:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="myscript.js">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.css" />
```

Then I have

```
<body id="mobile">
<div id="wrapper" data-role="page">
```

And then the content of the page

My script is executed as [documented](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0-rc.1/docs/api/events.html) on jquerymobile.com

```
$("#wrapper").live('pageinit', function() {
```

Am I missing something? Any help will be deeply appreciated.

Comment: It seems like the extra div's are added to the current page when navigating to another page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try adding data-dom-cache="false" it should look like this

```
<body id="mobile">
<div id="wrapper" data-role="page" data-dom-cache="false">
```

Comment: Unfortunately this did not do the trick. It seems to execute to script again when navigating away from the page. Any other ideas?

Comment: could you explain your problem more. i don't quite follow you. does pageinit fires more than once? try with a couple of alerts to know how many times it fires

Comment: Actually I forgot to empty the cache, and now it works with `data-dom-cache="false"` - THANK YOU!

Comment: If you actually want to get this working without disabling DOM caching you need to understand that jQM normally adds pages to the current DOM, you need to move your $("#wrapper").live('pageinit', function() { outside of the <div data-role="page"> so you don't add multiple listeners.

Answer (score 1):

As [Clarence commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9836112/jquerymobile-script-runs-twice-on-each-pageload#comment12547262_9836157), a better solution is to move the `<script>` tag outside of the `<div>` with `data-role="page"`

```
<body id="mobile">
  <div id="wrapper" data-role="page">
    <!-- stuff -->
  </div>
  <script>
    $("#wrapper").live('pageinit', function() {
      // more stuff
    });
  </script>
</body>
```